# How to I get swift to not return a salted cipher text, and instead return an unsalted version of the cipher text?

Tags: python, ios, swift, encryption, rsa

I have a swift app that uses a RSA public key to send data to a python server, and have the server decrypt it with the server private key. However, swift returns a different cipher text each time. Is there any way to have it not salt it?

I've tried using SwiftyRSA, and SwiftUtils to implement the encryption, and while asking others for help, it seems swift automatically salts the message.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ....
    do{
        let data = "\(message!)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        // tag name to access the stored public key in keychain
        let TAG_PUBLIC_KEY = "com.example.keyPublic"
        let encryptStr = "encrypted_message="
        let encryptStrData = encryptStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let keyString = getKeyStringFromPEMString(PEMString: """
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
""")
        let encryptedData = try RSAUtils.encryptWithRSAPublicKey(data: data, pubkeyBase64: keyString, tagName: TAG_PUBLIC_KEY)!
        let length = encryptStrData.count + encryptedData.count
        var array = [UInt8](repeating:0, count:length)
        encryptStrData.copyBytes(to: &array, count: encryptStrData.count)
        encryptedData.copyBytes(to: &array+encryptStrData.count, count: encryptedData.count)
        var st=""
        for byte in encryptedData{
            st += String(format:"%02X", byte)
        }
        print("ENCRYPTED MESSAGE")
        print(st)
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
    }
    ...
    //Key function - remove header and footer
    func getKeyStringFromPEMString(PEMString: String) -> String {
        let keyArray = PEMString.split(separator: "\n") //Remove new line characters
        var keyOutput : String = ""
        for item in keyArray {
            if !item.contains("-----") { //Example: -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
                keyOutput += item //Join the text together as a single string
            }
        }
        return keyOutput
    }
    ....
}
```

```py
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
from base64 import b64decode
def decText(encTest):
    random_generator = Random.new().read
    key = RSA.generate(2048, random_generator)
    with open('private.pem','r') as f:
        key=RSA.importKey(f.read())
    rawCipherData = b64decode(encTest)
    decrypted = key.decrypt(encTest)
    print(decrypted)
    return decrypted
```

Here's the plaintext.
`33ba884d57161df955de45c50e3bba69c83233402bf460906b919bc0806b44356112b6e0b8dd8f2f5804d5b527e996ba91e91015915f03d0292d89b7ecfc3c44`

And here's the ciphertext
`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`

Here's the hex of what python outputs with this cipher text:
`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`

Comment: The RSA padding has a random part so it is correct that the encryption returns a randomized ciphertext. Without the padding the RSA is seriously unsecure

Comment: So how should I fix this? Is there a way to have python handle this issue?

Comment: There is nothing to *fix*, it is so by design and you should not change it (you can implement your own RSA encryption with static padding, but I strongly voice against such foolishness). Event the ciphertext is randomized, it will decrypt the the same plaintext. Maybe if you update your question and explain why you want to have static output, someone could help you achieve your goal (even other way)

Comment: What the key issue is is that the python script won't decrypt the ciphertext. That's the issue I was referring to. It will not decrypt the ciphertext back to plaintext

Comment: what exception do you receive? in the python script - do you cut off the prepended text `encrypted_message=`? I see the swift code is doing hex encoding, but python base64 decoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see difference in encoding and decoding

in the Swift encryption code the encryption seems to output:

```
hex_encode( "encrypted_message=" + encrypt( data ) )
```

while the python is doing

```
base64_decode( ciphertext )
```

If there's something else, you will need to provide working and verifiable code sample, inputs you use and exception you get

Comment: Here's one of the class files I'm using. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/btnguyen2k/swiftutils/master/SwiftUtils/RSAUtils.swift

Comment: @trainboy2019 The problem is not in encryption itself, but how you **encode and decode** data. You need to use the same algorithm and add no additional text. You need to use THE SAME encoding (hex or base64, just keep it the same). And skip the fancy text constants

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue, I got it to work now, the only issue is it throws a lot of garbage data that I have to get rid of, but I can split the text and work from there.